# Stacking multiple groups of textblocks and texboxes with automatic gap between the groups

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF and I am having a problem in designing my UI.

I want to show a row of controls for a Customer's fields: Name, Phone, Age, Address:

`Group_1 [ Textblock1 <fixed gap> Textbox1 ] <variable_gap> Group_2 [ Textblock2 <fixed gap> Textbox2 ]` and so on....

For example:

for a customer:

```
name_textblock Text_box <variable gap> Phone Text_box <variable gap> Age Text_box <variable gap> Address Text_box
```

See attached image too:

[image]

I want to group `one textblock and one textbox` (invisible grouping, no group border etc.) together with a fixed gap, and then the gap between 2 such group should vary depending on the screen resolution / DPI.

How make it? I am very new to WPF and this is my my first UI in WPF.

Comment: You can create a `Grid` with multiple stack panel inside, where text blocks are placed

Comment: can you give details? like grid ColumnDefinitions should be what value?

Comment: ColumnWidth should be `*`

Comment: So, a grid of 4 columns with * as width, and each grid.column has 1 stackpanel Each stackpanel has 1 textblock and 1 textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup a `Grid` like this:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <TextBlock Text="123" Margin="0,0,8,0" />
    <TextBox Width="30" />
  </StackPanel>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <TextBlock Text="123" Margin="0,0,8,0" />
    <TextBox Width="30" />
  </StackPanel>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <TextBlock Text="123" Margin="0,0,8,0" />
    <TextBox Width="30" />
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

---

By default, the `TextBox` doesn't stretch to fill remaining space. It is designed to take the minimum required space and will grow on input.

The following solution will force the `TextBox` to consume the remaining column space using a `DockPanel` as container.

Note: if you don't want to have the `TextBox` stretch to fill the complete remaining space, you can control it by setting either the `DockPanel.Width`, `DockPanel.MaxWidth` or the `TextBox.MaxWidth` property.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <DockPanel Grid.Column="0" LastChildFill="True">
    <TextBlock Text="123" />
    <TextBox Margin="4,0,8,0" />
  </DockPanel>
  <DockPanel Grid.Column="1" LastChildFill="True">
    <TextBlock Text="123" />
    <TextBox Margin="4,0,8,0" />
  </DockPanel>
  <DockPanel Grid.Column="2" LastChildFill="True">
    <TextBlock Text="123" />
    <TextBox Margin="4,0,8,0" />
  </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Depending on your scenario you may consider to use a horizontal `ItemsControl`.

Comment: It is working fine, thanks. however, one small issues that I want textbox to fill the leftover space of each stackpanel after textblock width. I mean textbox.width = stackpanel.width - textblock.width. I tried  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" for textbox, but it is not working.